# Golang down casting struct

Tags: pointers, go

I'm relatively new at Go and struggling with initialising structs.

The classic example is

```
type Car struct {
    wheelCount int
}
type Ferrari struct {
   Car
   driver string
}

// Initialise Ferrari
f := Ferrari{Car{4},"Some Dude"}
```

My question is, how do I get a *Ferrari if I only have a *Car created with a constructor?

I would like to be able to to something like the following

```
func NewCar(wheels int) *Car{
    return &Car{wheels};
}

car := NewCar(4);
ferrari := Ferrari{car,"Some Dude"}; // ERROR cannot use car (type *Car) as type Car in field value
```

Am I approaching the problem incorrectly? Can one simply dereference the car somehow?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear. You can't use `Car` as a pointer to `Car`. You need to either redefine your `Ferrari` to embed a pointer to `Car`

```
type Ferrari struct {
    *Car
    driver string
}
```

or to dereference the pointer in the literal:

```
ferrari := Ferrari{*car, "Some Dude"}
```

Comment: That works thanks. I had a different issue that caused the straight forward answer not to work. Now the world makes sense again.